# slow motion software with user interface

Tags: camera, software-recommendation

I'm not sure if this question is too broad, but I just start with my raspberry pi and a pi camera module. I can configure the camera correctly and take some photos using the command line, however, I'm trying to find a software to capture photos to make some slow animation videos with my kid. Since my kid is six years old I'm looking for a software with a user interface to make it easy and funny for him.

Can somebody recommend a good one?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking for search terms try "linux stop motion software". Unfortunately I haven't tried any so I can't give a recommendation, but this looks like what you described: http://linuxstopmotion.org/